# Matlab Smoothing Function Produces Extreme Value

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, smoothing

I'm trying to plot a smoothed version of the following figure(a post-stimulus time histogram):[image]

However when I use the command `plot(tvec,smooth(vec,101))`, the plot produced has an extreme final value which is exaggerated the higher I increase the span: 
[image]

What is causing this effect? Every smoothing method I have tried produces an extremely large final value. Surely this can't be its true value...?

Comment: I don't get it, you're trying to smooth discrete data ? Why ? Are you trying to get the probability density function ? In this case use the matlab `pdf`function

Comment: I'm trying to make the plot less discontinuous by averaging over wider time bins. At the moment, the figure shows values for every 5*10^-5 seconds. Could it potentially be something to do with the fact that there are no values to the right of the final value, meaning it can't take the average?

Comment: but so, can't you just reduce the number of bins directly in your histogram ?

Comment: Smoothign does not produce an extreme value.... That value is 4 times smaller than in your original data. if the last N values are 4500, smoothing them wont make them zero or anything.... Also, why are you smoothing something that has only 3 possible values? Its discrete....

Comment: Maybe I've misinterpreted the smooth function. The intention was to convert the discrete 3-valued plot into a more continuous one with a larger range of values.  I'm following section IV of the guide here [link](http://neuroscience.ucdavis.edu/goldman/Tutorials_files/SpikeTrainAnalysis.pdf) .